# Flex Mobile Alarm - Local Notification

Tags: android, iphone, apache-flex, flex4.5, alarm

I'm using **flex 4.6** for developing mobile application. I need to create an alarm application with Flex for iPhone/Android. I came to know we have to use/schedule local notification class to build an alarm application and i found an example here @ http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/notification.html

But from the zip file you can download from the above link, only shows how to trigger notification class by a button click.

How do I trigger this by automatic at a particular time period to make an alarm application?

Comment: I need the same, did you find something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to create ANE for both iPhone and Android using native code and call in on Flex. Refer this link for know more about ANE

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-4aefe03513238d8a1b8-8000.html

Here are some examples http://sleepydesign.blogspot.in/2012/07/ane-free-air-native-extensions.html